# In matplotlib errorbar how to pass colour different points with different colours?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, errorbar

I have

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(shape[1], shape[0], figsize=(9, 3 * shape[1]), sharey=True)
```

```
    for idx, ax in enumerate(axs.reshape(-1)):

        categorical_labels = ...
        values = ...
        errors = ...
        colours = ...


        ax.errorbar(categorical_labels, values, yerr=errors, fmt='.', ecolor=colours, mfc=colours, mec=colours)
```

This doesn't work because `ecolor`, `mfc` and, `mec` don't accept a list of colours (one colour for each point), as soon as it sees a list of colours it assumes it is an RGBA colour. Thus it gives the error:

> ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: ('lime', 'magenta', 'darkorange', 'cyan', 'cornflowerblue', 'cornflowerblue', 'lime', 'magenta', 'darkorange', 'cyan')

I can get around this problem by looping over all the points and plotting them indivudually:

```
for i, v in enumerate(values):
    ax.errorbar([categorical_labels[i]], [values[i]], yerr=[errors[i]], fmt='.', ecolor=colours[i], mfc=colours[i], mec=colours[i])
```

which gives me something like:
[image]

which is what I want.

But is there a way to do it without looping all the points??
All other answers on stackoverflow use `cmap` or `colormap` but `errorbar` does not have those arguments.

Comment: The two options are: You can either use as many calls to `ax.errorbar` as you have colors. Or you can create one `scatter` and one `LineCollection` with all colors respectively.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ! Could you give an example of how one would do this with `LineCollection` ?

Comment: Each line of the collection would go from (x, y-yerr) to (x,y+yerr).

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. Thank you!